# Search Spreadsheet and Return Row Value

Tags: excel, combobox, find, row, userform

Afternoon

I have been working on a few userforms for Excel, this particular problem is relating to a find and return type function where I have a combobox that is populated by a criteria in a spreadsheet.

The intention is that from the combo list it will search the task item from the spreadsheet, so that the users can update progress. The problem I have is that the information will be written to two sheets, therefore the search function will be mirrored to another sheet where if the value is not found it will add a row, or if the value is found it will update the values in the row.

What I have below is a piece of code that I am trying to return the ROW value for the searched uncompleted task. It doesn't fail but, doesn't return the ROW Value.

```
Private Sub CB_TaskList_Click()

Dim Found As Range
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = wb.Sheets("Tracker")

If Me.CB_TaskList.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Missing Entry"
Else
    Set Found = ws.Range("A:A").Find(Me.CB_TaskList.Value, _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
    
    Me.TB_Row.Value = ws.Cells(Found.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).Value
    
End If

End Sub
```

Not sure if I have gone completely off track, any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the above code to work. Feel pretty dumb as it was a really simple solution:

```
Private Sub CB_TaskList_Click()

Dim Task As Range
Dim xWorkbook As Workbook: Set xWorkbook = ThisWorkbook
Dim xWorksheet As Worksheet

Set xWorksheet = xWorkbook.Sheets("Tracker")

If Not Me.CB_TaskList.Value = "" Then
    
    Set Task = xWorksheet.Range("A:A").Find(Me.CB_TaskList.Value, _
                                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                MatchCase:=False)
    Me.TB_Row.Value = Task.Row
    
   Else
    
    MsgBox "Missing Entry"
            
   End If

   End Sub
```